# Dvd Maker (Where can I find one?)

Tags: dvd

Okay it appears the only thing that is preventing me from using Ubuntu as my primary (only) OS, is the fact that I cannot burn a movie.  I have tried DeVeDe, DVDStyler, Brasero, and K3b is just not understandable.  Is there a program such as Windows DVD Maker, or iSkysoft DVD Creator, Nero, or anything like that?  Basically point to the file (avi., mp4.) create title, put disk in and click burn.  That's it.  This is very common with any other OS, however I just cannot find it on Ubuntu.

Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
Core i3
Nvidia 310m
8gb ram

Comment: What doesn't work with the first three programs you tried?

Comment: You may want to read: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2150361

Comment: Try and learn K3B, it's the best and won't mess up your DVD discs.

Answer (score 0):

K3b actually works very well once you get use to the program. However if you are looking for a Windows like dvd maker (point and click) I would recommend [Open Shoot](http://www.openshotvideo.com/http://www.openshotvideo.com/?m=1). Its very easy to use and a more windows program feel.